# Como cachar una url entre Intents de Android

Tags: android, android-intent

Tengo una app nativa de android con 2 Activities.

1.- Main.java: contiene un webview donde se despliega un POS web con url: www.posWeb.com

2.- Camera.java: esta activity manda llamar un lector de codigo de barras para escanear los productos que se van a buscar en inventario o agregar al carrito.

La idea que tengo es enviar el codigo de barras leido de Camera.java hacia el Main, via el siguiente codigo

```
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    i.putExtra("codeBar",rawResult.getText());
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
```

Pero el problema que tengo es que necesito que el webview cargue una url dependiendo de si se inició la aplicación o si regresó desde Camera.java

```
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
        }
    });
     webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
     webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
     webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

Actualmente lo estoy manejando de la siguiente forma:

```
             if(getIntent().hasExtra("codeBar")) //el extra que envie desde Camera.java
              webView.loadUrl(url+getIntent().getStringExtra("codeBar"));
             else
               webView.loadUrl(url);
```

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza `startActivityForResult`. Esto habilita al activity que se esta ejecutando pasar data para la activity que la ejecuto:

En el `MainActivity` llamarias a `Camara` activity asi:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Camera.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
```

Cuando obtengas el QR en `Camera`, finalizas el activity asignado la data del QR con `setResult` pasandole el Intent con la data:

```
Intent data = new Intent();
data.putExtra("qr",rawResult.getText());
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);   
finish();
```

Cuando se finaliza el activity Camera, setResult le enviada data a MainActivity y para recibirlos sobreescribimos el metodo `onActivityResult`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 100) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String dataQR = data.getStringExtra("qr");
            webView.loadUrl(url+dataQR);
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Codigo aqui si la respuesta fue cancelada
        }
    }
}
```